# Storm-kafka 0.8 plus, Can I read from the latest offset?

Tags: apache-storm

I have a topology with Kafka spout somewhat like below

```
SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(zkBrokerHosts, "some-topic","", "some-id");
spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
...

builder.setSpout("kafkaSpout",new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig),1);
```

And of course it works fine.

Considering the case that my topology fails and running it up again, I want KafkaSpout to read from the latest offset of that topic not from last offset the consumer have read.

Is there any option? I tried

```
spoutConfig.startOffsetTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
```

but seems it doesn't work as I want. and neither kafkaConfig.forceStartOffsetTime(-2);

Let me know if you have some idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `kafkaConfig.forceStartOffsetTime(-1)`. `-1` for the latest Kafka offset, and `-2` for the earliest available offset.

EDIT:

Also, you can force the spout to start consuming from any desired offset with the same option -- just pass the numeric offset as the only argument.

Ignore the "`Time`" in `forceStartOffsetTime`, the parameter name is a bit confusing. Offsets in Kafka are numbers and have no connection to any concept of time whatsoever. `-1` is just a special way of telling the Kafka spout to gather the latest offset from Kafka itself (idem `-2` for the earliest available offset).